# Primefaces dependency not able to import as the REPO url is blocked

Tags: maven, primefaces

I am working on a maven based Spring project.I have added following dependency for Primefaces.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
<artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
```

And following Repository,I am using

```
<repository>
<id>prime-repo</id>
<name>Prime Technology Maven Repository</name>
<url>http://repository.prime.com.tr</url>
<layout>default</layout>
```

But the problem is that the url http://repository.prime.com.tr is blocked in our network, so I manually copied jar file of primefaces at .m2 repo location.

Now the problem is , it is not picking the Primefaces dependency mentioned in POM.xml.It is not even showing it in Java Build Path inside STS.

Can somebody please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually copying the file into the `.m2/repository` might not be sufficient.
You can try to install it manually in your repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=path/to/local/primefaces.jar
                         -DgroupId=org.primefaces
                         -DartifactId=primefaces
                         -Dversion=2.2
                         -Dpackaging=jar
```