# Maven Build Error (Could not resolve dependencies)

Tags: maven, build

I am trying to build the software Online-Whiteboard (http://code.google.com/p/online-whiteboard/) using maven. According to the website linked above, I need to use the follow command:

```
mvn jetty:run
```

However, when I run that command I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project whiteboard-showcase: Could not resolve 
dependencies for project com.googlecode.online-whiteboard:whiteboard-showcase:war:0.1: 
Failed to collect dependencies for [commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5 (compile), 
commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6 (compile), com.sun.faces:jsf-
api:jar:2.1.2 (compile), com.sun.faces:jsf-impl:jar:2.1.2 (compile), 
org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:2.2.1 (compile), org.primefaces.themes:cupertino:jar:1.0.1 
(compile), com.ocpsoft:prettyfaces-jsf2:jar:3.3.0 (compile), javax.el:el-api:jar:2.2 
(compile), org.glassfish.web:el-impl:jar:2.2 (compile), javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0 
(compile), javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (compile), javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2 
(compile), com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.7.1 (compile), org.atmosphere:atmosphere-
jersey:jar:0.8-SNAPSHOT (compile), org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-
servlet_3.0_spec:jar:1.0 (compile), org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.2 (compile), 
org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:jar:1.6.2 (compile), junit:junit:jar:4.8.2 (test)]: Failed to read 
artifact descriptor for org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:2.2.1: Could not transfer artifact
 org.primefaces:primefaces:pom:2.2.1 from/to JBoss (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/): 
Access denied to: 
http://repository.jboss.org/maven2//org/primefaces/primefaces/2.2.1/primefaces-2.2.1.pom ->
 [Help 1]
```

I've never used Maven before, so really have no clue what I am doing here; I tried looking up what this could be but couldn't find anything (helpful). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, when you mvn command, it will try to download the dependency from the available repository location. but for some reason in your project maven is trying to download dependency from following location which doesn't exist or you can invalid.

http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/

so try using following repository location it should solve the problem if primeface jar is present in the location. i guess it is host there.

http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about prime-faces.  Looking at the `pom.xml` of the Online-Whiteboard, I see   a reference to

```
<repository>
    <id>prime-repo</id>
    <name>Prime Technology Maven Repository</name>
    <url>http://repository.prime.com.tr</url>
</repository>
```

Looks like this url is invalid.  Here is a [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779997/primefaces-dependency-not-able-to-import-as-the-repo-url-is-blocked). According to [this primeface download link](http://primefaces.org/downloads.html), you could try using the following instead and see if it helps you to proceed.

```
<repository>  
    <id>prime-repo</id>  
    <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
    <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>     
</repository
```

Comment: Thanks; this was one of this incorrect repositories in the pom.xml file. Maven is now able to retrieve everything.